# Are Loopback REST API Filters Case Insensitive on Linux?

Tags: linux, rest, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, loopbackjs

We're implementing Loopback for our REST API and currently using Windows.

Ultimately we'll be running on both Windows and Linux.

Does Loopback support case insensitive filters on Linux like it does on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this never got answered, but I think this is up to the datasource connector, not the OS. If you connect your model to MySQL, for example, then you would need to make sure the connector is either adding the collation, or you do manually (or you set MySQL to do so). The point is, case sensitivity in filters like `where` has nothing to do with the OS.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the actual URI used by the REST framework rather than the literal files in the OS.